# Get the index in order of values from max to min without sorting the output index list and amend another list as well

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to get the indices of the values in the array from maximum to minimum without sorting the indices positions. Here is the current code I have

```
s = [20, 30, 45, 14, 59]
ans = sorted(range(len(s)), key=lambda k: s[k], reverse=True)
print ans
```

but I am getting the output as `[4, 2, 1, 0, 3]` which is based on sorting. I don't want the sorted list of indexes instead I want them in same position. Output should be `[3, 2, 1, 4, 0]`. Is there any way to achieve this?

For 2D: Now if there is another array (only with -1, 0, 1) associated with the first array `sv = [(1,0), (-1,1), (-1,0), (0,-1), (1,1)]`. Here each value in sv is indexed and bind to same output array `[3, 2, 1, 4, 0]`. Now based on certain condition say

```
for i in s if any val[i] < max(val[i])*25/100
```

value will be removed from s as well as sv and also its indexing. So in above case new s, new sv and new indexing output will be

```
s = [20, 30, 45, 59]
indexing = [3, 2, 1, 0]
sv = [(1,0), (-1,1), (-1,0), (1,1)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict that maps each list item to its sorted index:

```
mapping = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(sorted(s, reverse=True))}
print([mapping[i] for i in s])
```

This outputs:

```
[3, 2, 1, 4, 0]
```

Comment: That's a very clear and acceptable solution for this. Is this also valid for 2d array's? I have learned something new today by your answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Not too sure what you mean by applying the answer to a 2D array though. Can you give an example? You can edit your question with the example.

Comment: I have edited the question with the example. This solution can be mapped with the sv as well to get the desired output? I think it also need some weightage condition like this >> for i in s if any val[i] < max(val[i])*25/100

Answer (score 2):

```
s = [20, 30, 45, 14, 59]
ss = sorted(s,reverse=True)


print([s.index(i) for i in ss]) ## gives [4, 2, 1, 0, 3]
print([ss.index(i) for i in s]) ## gives [3, 2, 1, 4, 0]
```